# Locating .so files in Android Studio version 3.0+

Tags: android-studio-3.0

I have installed Android Studio Version 3.5  and I am trying to build a native library for my C++ source codes. I want to provide the .so files to someone to be later packaged with an Android API.

I read that in Android Studio 3.0+, jnilibs don't have to be configured separately as all the source code C++ files will be packaged into the apk automatically.

But in my case, I want to access the *.so files and I am not able to locate them.

I have tried to locate the .so files in my application in apps -> build -> intermediates -> merged_native_libs. The .so files are also available in the stripped_native_libs and cmake folder. I am not sure which ones are the final ones which represent my shared library.

Comment: I have implemented ndk crashlytics and i am using `merged_native_libs` to get libs and getting crashes in firebase also